# left or margin-left doesnt work with %

Tags: css

I have a div nested in a div. I am trying to display some text and that works. However what I want is that the text is center aligned i.e. it has a `left: -50%`. But it does nothing. But when I do something like `left: 20px` then the text moves left by 20px. How can I achieve moving my div left by 50%?

Even with position relative I have no change

```
.currentText{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

using `float` destroys my display

```
.currentText{
  float: left;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

My html (jsx in my case) is:

```
<div style={{ marginLeft: `${currentPer}%`, marginRight: `${100 - currentPer}%` }}>
  <div className={s.currentText}>
    {intl.formatMessage(messages.boo)}
  </div>
</div>
<div style={{ marginLeft: `${currentPer}%`, marginRight: `${100 - currentPer}%` }}>
  <div
    className={s.down}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste your HTML here, so we can help.

Comment: I think the main problem is that it's a `display: inline` element. You can try to give it `display: inline-block` or `block`. But better practice for centering text would be `text-align: center` or the transform method.

Comment: `text-align` will center the text in my div. But what I want here is that half of my text will be outside my div and the rest inside. So the left margin sort of acts like the center axis

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get something like that ? :

https://jsfiddle.net/nL7bjgbx/20/

i've used jQuery to get the witdh of the child div & offset it of half the value

```
var widthDiv = $(".childDiv").css('width');
var rule = '-'+(widthDiv.replace("px", "")/2)+'px';

$(".childDiv").css('margin-left', rule);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the text to be aligned center add this `.targetText { text-align: center }`

Comment: `text-align` will center the text in my div. But what I want here is that half of my text will be outside my div and the rest inside. So the left margin sort of acts like the center axis

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested divs, you could use positioning like below.

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f0f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Text</div>
</div>
```